# Access my local server by hostname or servername

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, tomcat, hostname

I have a local host server hosting a few applications in tomcat which comes through a apache proxy

The client or User trying to access these application has to access them like

```
10.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/appName
```

> **OR**

```
10.XXX.XXX.XX/appName
```

But I want to replace the ip address with soem other name related to my applications.
But I cannot go and enter the host name of the server in each users `/etc/host`
Nor do I want to be setting up DNS.

Is there another way to do this.

I am using

```
ProxyPass XXX YYY
```

to redirect all applications of tomcat to port 80

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up and configure DNS.

Comment: Thanks, but any way other than that?

Comment: You could edit every hosts file, but that's obviously a bad solution. What's the problem with setting up DNS?

Comment: @S.M.09 Those _are_ the *only* two ways to do it.